# Signal neovim to reread its configuration

Tags: colors, nvim

I have a script with which I toggle between a dark and a light colorscheme. The terminal emulator I use (termite) rereads its configuration when receiving the signal USR1, so when toggling my colorscheme I send USR1 to all termite instances so that the colorscheme is updated immediatly.

Does there exist some possibility to convince neovim to reread its configuration (from outside of neovim)?

I couldn't really find a list of what neovim makes of unix signals. It also doesn't need to be a signal, as far as I understand neovim has some concepts of "server" and "frontend", so I guess something like connecting to each server and issuing to reload the configuration would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can remotely control vim via the [remote feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760014/how-can-i-configure-vim-so-that-when-i-send-the-process-a-usr1-signal-it-saves-a). For neovim I found the [neovim-remote](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote) which makes it easy to send a command to an already running nvim process. The following snippet iterates through every nvim process (discovered by neovim-remote) and sends a command to source the config file:

```
for path in $(nvr --nostart --serverlist)
do
  nvr --nostart --servername $path -cc 'so ~/.config/nvim/init.vim'
done
```

This assumes that the config is present in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`. If your config is in a different file it should be replaced there. If there are different nvims with different configurations loaded (e.g. via the `-u <configfile>` flag which loads a different config file) this script will ignore that and command each instance to load the same config. I would think `nvr --c 'so $MYVIMRC'` should work, but it didn't for me.

The first `--nostart` is probably superfluous, but it shouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that most of the solutions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/132029/how-do-you-reload-your-vimrc-file-without-restarting-vim) should also work with `neovim`.

Since you are on *nix the first one to try is probably: `:so ~/.vimrc`

Comment: The problem is that (as far as I understand) I have to manually issue that command in every (n)vim instance I'm currently running. I'm looking for a solution to automate that, e.g. something that "logs into each nvim instance" and issues the command.